# Make a Firefox add-on to inject some DIVs and add styles. That's it

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon

I am going to ask a VERY general question. I was working on a bookmarklet and decided to create a few browser extensions as well. I was able to make Safari and Chrome extensions pretty quickly but when it came to FF, I was a failure.

I used their builder but it kept giving errors even when I was using their sample code cut and pasted.

If someone could give me a simple step in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Literally, all I am trying to do is make the add-on button in the add-ons bar clickable and perform either a function or directly an if statement that checks for the existance of the DIVs and if they don't exist, create them, and if they do exist, destroy them. Basically a toggle.

I have read most (I am sure not all) of their docs in reference to this, but cannot make it work.

I am not looking for the code to do this, but I am missing something.

Comment: If you already have sample code, why not post it and give the errors. Then someone can help you troubleshoot. Right now your question basically says - I need example code for a ff extension. This can be googled easily. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ff%20extension%20tutorial&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=77b865c837c23bff&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1680&bih=925

Comment: thanks for the reply. i was not even able to make an alert() work. that is where i was starting. i am not looking for the code per se, just a point in the right direction, a corresponding tutorial. like i said, i was unable to get their sample code to work. it may have been a problem of their browser based builder. thanks

Comment: How can people help you without knowing the error message?

Comment: i actually got it working. thanks for for looking. the working code is above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
var widgets = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");

var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "div-show",
  label: "Show divs",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript:
    'alert("foo");'
    });
 }

});
```